# Audio mixer design

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

I have a few questions about the mixer design in the schematic below:
[image: Audio mixer schematic]

What purpose do the 22pf capacitors serve?
Can I ommit the 1k line out resistor?
Is it OK if I use the hot pin of a XLR as input?

I will not use the headphone part of the design.

Comment: Can you? Yes. But why would you want to? The design would become a lot less stable. What's the idea behind wanting to leave them out?

Comment: @Mast The only thing bothering me is the 1k resistor which limits the current output of the op amp.

Comment: If the current isn't high enough, put a booster trap behind it. But the mixer should do only one thing: mixing. And preferably in a stable manner. What you're suggesting is a high-output noise mixer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) The 22 pF capacitors improve stability. A mixer sometimes drives a fairly long cable, which appears as a capacitive load, which can cause opamps to oscillate. So the 22 pF capacitors improve phase margin. They also reduce gain at high frequencies (well above the audio band) which can help in electrically noisy environments (radio transmitters, studio lighting dimmers, etc).

2) The 1k resistors help isolate the opamp outputs from the same capacitive load (long cable) and also protect the opamps against accidental short circuits on the outputs. (Some jacks can momentarily short while being plugged in). So, recommended (but you may get away with reducing them to 470 or 220 ohms, if you aren't too worried about making your mixer bomb-proof.)

3) If your XLR inputs are driven from a balanced source, you can use the hot pin as your input, but you must return the "cold" leg to ground to complete the circuit. (Via another 470 or 1K resistor, in case the driving end isn't properly balanced or properly protected). This means your mixer has unbalanced inputs, so it can pick up interference that a better mixer would reject. In a home studio, this may not matter much.

Comment: The 22pF caps also help to avoid instability due to the capacitive nature of the summing node (Which can run all the way across the desk), capacitive load on the inverting input pin is seldom helpful for stability.

Comment: Thanks. Also I assume it is OK to lower the freeback resistor in order to increase gain.

Comment: Increase feedback resistors to increase gain.

Comment: @Transistor Yeah, thanks. For some reason I though I lowered the resistor value in my simulation.

Answer (score 9):

> What purpose do the 22pf capacitors serve?

Audio mixers can have many inputs sharing the same virtual earth at the op-amp Vin- input (see pin 6 of the TL084 below). This adds a lot of parasitic capacitance (purple box above) from Vin- to ground and creates a peak in the amplification of the op-amps internal input noise: -

[image]

Engineers refer to a phenomena called `noise gain` and that explains what is happening here. Irrespective of whether a real input is connected or not, this capacitance (in the orange boxes above) causes the op-amp gain to rise quite significantly at high frequencies: -

[image]

Whether R1 connects to a real input or not, C1 (the parasitic capacitance of the mixer's extended input infrastructure) produces gain in the op-amp beyond a certain frequency and this will boost noise and be a significant nuisance.

### Solution

A capacitor is added across the feedback resistor that reduces `noise gain`.

The 22 pF capacitors in the green box are not related to noise gain reduction and arbitrarily reduce high frequency gain in those op-amp stages.

> Can I ommit the 1k line out resistor?

Not really, a lot of audio gear has a 1 kohm output impedance and that is what is happening here. But, if you are re-purposing the circuit for something else you'd need to be clearer about the application.

> Is it OK if I use the hot pin of a XLR as input?

Which one are you thinking about and what type of XLR plug/socket?: -

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The 1Kohm line out resistors also reduce reverse-EMI distortion, with the EMI/RFI passing from the opamp Vout ---- through the 22pF Cfeedback - to the summing node.

I first read of this phenomena --- where radio frequency energy on the OUTPUT WIRES is conducted backward thru the feedback network --- in discussion of "how to improve the performance of your vacuum tube preamp". That magazine article was comparing the detailed circuits of various 1950/1960 audio RIAA preamps, versus their reputation among audiophiles. Some circuits with "gritty" reputation had that risk-of-rfi-in-feedback-path.